# Is there any way to take my old internet connections with me when doing a new install?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, home-directory

I have `/home` on a seperate partition, so every time when  I do a new install of Ubuntu, I take my program settings with me. This works fine for most programs, but I still have to retype my Wi-Fi passwords after each install.

Instead, I'd like to take my old passwords with me as well. How can I get that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can save the contents of **/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections** and then put them back into place after your install.  You should have one file per connection and it will have your password in plaintext, so be careful with what you do with the files.

I have /home on a separate partition too, but I always back-up /etc too as there are things in there I don't want to redo, like my autofs setup.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good way to go - either copy and restore `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` or backup `/etc`.

Comment: Be careful restoring all of /etc, I keep it because it's nice when you remember things like this that you want back.  There's some stuff in there that shouldn't be copied back I suspect.